# Microsoft Custom Translator and Speech Translation API

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator

Recently we using Microsoft Cloud service to build a custom translation system. Our goal is to have the capability of general translation and add-on custom translation in the same system.

I'm using MS translation speech and build up custom translator model (customtranslator.ai)

However, I cannot find the document of custom translator API and I found 2 kinds of speech translator in MS service:

1. Translation Speech

   - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator-speech/
2. Speech Translation (preview)

   - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speech-translation/
3. Speech Service

   - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/

May I know which API should I use and which documentation I should follow?
Currently, I'm using the Translator Speech API (1)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Speech Translation API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-translation) is one of the features of [Speech Service (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/overview) which is the latest, while the [Translator Speech API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator-speech/) is the older version and was released individually, not part of the Speech Service just like the [Bing Speech API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/home).

So, to keep it short, the answer is Speech Service, including its features which is in your case Speech Translation API because it is the latest.

You can also find the documentation for the [Custom Translator (preview)](https://portal.customtranslator.azure.ai/) on GitHub through [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/Custom-Translator-Documentation)

Comment: Thank you @Ali!
Does the old Translator Speech API have the same ability as the new Speech Service?  Is the Speech Service API stable enough? Thanks!

Comment: I can tell by looking at the About section of both documentations (the old Translator Speech API and the new Speech Translation API) that they are pretty much the same, but the new one actually has more frequent documentation updates, new code samples, and more, and yes the Speech Service is stable enough as it simply unites the previous services under one subscription and adds more upon that from improvements and features.